# Set value of asp:HiddenField in Client side and Get that value in Server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

I'm having trouble with setting value of asp:HiddenField in aspx webpage and getting that value in C# code behind.

HTML brief code

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getData() {
      markerData = [ <%= getMarkerData() %> ];
    }

    function showData() {
      ...
      getData();
      ...
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:hiddenfield id="hfvarFrom" runat="server" />
    <asp:hiddenfield id="hfvarTo" runat="server" />
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="divInformation" style="width: 300px;">
      <div class="panel-body" style="height: 650px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <asp:button id="btnLoadData" runat="server" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" text="LOAD DATA" onclientclick="javascript:showData(); return false;" usesubmitbehavior="false" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#<% =btnLoadData.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
        $('#<% =hfvarFrom.ClientID %>').attr('value', '2016-06-14');
        $('#<% =hfvarFrom.ClientID %>').attr('value', '2016-06-14');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

C# brief code

```
protected String getMarkerData()
{
    String from = hfvarFrom.Value;
    String to = hfvarTo.Value;
    return getMarkerObjects(from, to);
}
```

I'm having 2 asp:HiddenField and a asp:Button. When OnClientClick is called, showData() will call getData() and of course, run other functions. getData() will call getMarkerData() in Code behind.
The thing is, I couldn't get HiddenField's value from the code behind. Rather than that, everything works fine.

Please, give me some advise as I'm newbie in web coding

Thank all

Comment: Are you calling `getMarkerData` from code behind? and is it called?

Comment: Yes, it is called. The only thing doesn't work here is hfvarFrom.Value. It always returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string from = hfvarFrom.Value;
    string to = hfvarTo.Value;
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=hfvarFrom.ClientID %>').val("2016-06-14");
            $('#<%=hfvarTo.ClientID %>').val("2016-06-15");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfvarFrom" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfvarTo" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="btnOK_Click" style="height: 29px; width: 37px" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But with this code, can I return value to my markerData since I need to append value into this markerData = [ <%= getMarkerData() %> ];

Comment: Just change the code behind for the button click event to call that method or something similar.I gave you the code which sets the value for the hidden field and can be accessed from code behind,now it's up to you to make the rest of the changes to make sure it works the way you want to

Comment: Yes, I did figure it out myself. Desired values will be assigned in OnClick function and pass to getMarkerObjects() which is called when page is reloaded. Thank you